# PHP file_get_content with SVGs

Tags: php, html, css, svg, icons

I would like to include a .svg in my page thank to PHP (I've created these SVG on illustrator CC)

So I use this bit of code :

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("ICON.svg"); ?>
```

Unfortunately, there is a problem. When the page is generated, there are two symbols that appear upon my icon :

> ]>

as you can see [here](http://alabama-pub.com/Mailing/test2.php).

May you please help me fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your code

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
<!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
]>
```

you should be able to just delete this symbols.
If this doesn't fix you problem try to delete the `[]`, I think you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the source of the page you'll see:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
]>
```

That symbol in the last line is the one you see, get rid of this terrible doctype declaration, replace it with something that makes sense and the problem is resolved...

Btw. you don't need all that generated garbage, you can just insert this part in an HTML document:

```
       <svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 316 316" enable-background="new 0 0 316 316" xml:space="preserve">
 <g>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M158,0C70.7,0,0,70.7,0,158s70.7,158,158,158s158-70.7,158-158S245.3,0,158,0z M158,283
            c-69,0-125-56-125-125S89,33,158,33s125,56,125,125S227,283,158,283z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M125.2,88.8c-0.8,1.5-3.1,4.2-6.7,6.9c-10.3,7.6-20.3,5-26.5-3.4c-7.5-10.2-4.4-21.1,4.6-27.8
            c3.5-2.6,6.7-3.8,8.3-4.1l2.6,6.4c-1.8,0.4-4.1,1.3-6.5,3c-5.3,3.9-7.1,10.2-2.3,16.8c4.4,6,10.7,7.1,16.7,2.7c2-1.5,4-3.6,4.9-5.1
            L125.2,88.8z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M155,63.4c2.6,11.8-2.9,20.6-13.5,23c-10.7,2.4-18.8-4.3-21.1-14.6c-2.4-10.8,2.7-20.4,13.3-22.8
            C144.9,46.5,152.8,53.4,155,63.4z M129.1,69.7c1.6,7.1,6,11.3,11.5,10.1c5.5-1.2,7.5-7.2,5.9-14.2c-1.4-6.5-5.8-11.3-11.4-10.1
            C129.5,56.7,127.5,62.7,129.1,69.7z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M177.8,48.5l-5,20.7c-1.5,6.2,0.1,9.9,4.2,10.9c4.3,1,7.3-1.4,8.9-7.7l5-20.7l8.1,2l-4.9,20.1
            c-2.7,11.1-9.6,15-19,12.7c-9.1-2.2-13.2-8.5-10.4-20l4.9-20L177.8,48.5z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M215.6,62.8c2.3,1.2,5.4,3.2,9.4,6.3c4.1,3.1,6.4,6.2,7.1,9.2c0.7,2.9,0.1,6.3-2.1,9.2
            c-2.2,2.9-5,4.6-8,4.9c-3.9,0.4-8-1.2-11.9-4.2c-0.9-0.7-1.6-1.3-2.2-1.9L200,96.7l-6.6-5L215.6,62.8z M212,81.1
            c0.5,0.6,1.1,1.1,2.1,1.9c3.5,2.7,7.1,2.6,9.4-0.4c2.1-2.7,1.4-5.7-1.9-8.3c-1.3-1-2.4-1.6-2.9-1.8L212,81.1z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M99.5,252.4c-1.7-0.4-4.9-1.9-8.3-4.8c-9.9-8.1-9.9-18.4-3.3-26.5c8-9.8,19.4-9.5,28-2.4
            c3.4,2.7,5.3,5.5,6,7l-5.5,4.1c-0.9-1.6-2.3-3.6-4.6-5.5c-5.1-4.2-11.7-4.4-16.9,2c-4.7,5.7-4.2,12.1,1.5,16.8
            c2,1.6,4.5,2.9,6.2,3.5L99.5,252.4z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M156.3,271.6l-20.3-4.6c-1-0.2-2.1-0.3-3.4-0.4c-1.3-0.2-2.7-0.3-4.4-0.7c-12.4-2.8-16.1-12.7-13.9-22.4
            c2.6-11.5,11.6-17.3,22.5-14.8c2,0.4,3.5,1,4.8,1.4c1.3,0.5,2.4,0.9,3.3,1.1l18.9,4.3l-1.5,6.7l-14.1-3.2l-1.7,7.5l13.3,3l-1.5,6.6
            l-13.3-3l-1.9,8.6l14.8,3.4L156.3,271.6z M140,237c-0.9-0.7-2.3-1.3-4.1-1.7c-5.6-1.3-11.3,1.9-13.1,9.8c-1.7,7.1,1.2,13,8.1,14.6
            c1.3,0.3,2.8,0.4,3.8,0.2L140,237z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M172.3,231.1l5.9,20.4c1.8,6.1,5,8.5,9.1,7.3c4.2-1.2,5.7-4.8,3.9-11.1l-5.9-20.4l8-2.3l5.8,19.9
            c3.2,11-0.8,17.8-10.1,20.5c-8.9,2.6-15.7-0.8-18.9-12.1l-5.7-19.8L172.3,231.1z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M195.3,223.9c1.8-2,4.7-4.8,8.1-7.6c4.2-3.5,7.7-5.3,11.1-5.3c2.8,0,5.4,1.2,7.5,3.8
            c3,3.7,2.4,8.3,0.7,11.2l0.1,0.1c2.7-0.8,5.3,0.2,8.2,2.2c3.5,2.5,7.5,5.5,8.9,6.2l-6.6,5.4c-1.1-0.4-3.7-2.2-7.4-5
            c-3.7-2.9-5.7-2.9-8.4-0.8l-2,1.6l9.2,11.3l-6.4,5.2L195.3,223.9z M211.8,231l2.5-2.1c3.2-2.6,3.8-5.8,1.8-8.3
            c-2.1-2.6-5-2.5-8-0.1c-1.6,1.3-2.4,2.1-2.8,2.6L211.8,231z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M140.1,146.1c-1.8,0-2.9,0.2-3.6,0.3v23.2c0.7,0.2,1.8,0.2,2.8,0.2c7.2,0.1,12-3.9,12-12.4
            C151.3,150,147,146.1,140.1,146.1z"/>
        <path fill="#55BFD7" d="M205,122c-13-13-34-13-47,0c-13-13-34-13-47,0s-13,34,0,47l47,47l47-47C218,156.1,218,135,205,122z
             M153.9,171.4c-3.7,3.1-9.4,4.6-16.3,4.6c-4.1,0-7.1-0.3-9.1-0.5v-34.8c2.9-0.5,6.8-0.7,10.8-0.7c6.7,0,11.1,1.2,14.5,3.8
            c3.7,2.7,6,7.1,6,13.3C159.7,163.9,157.3,168.6,153.9,171.4z M187.6,175.6H165v-35.4h21.8v6.6H173v7.4h13v6.5h-13v8.4h14.5V175.6z"
            />
    </g>
    <ellipse fill="#55BFD7" cx="-265" cy="29" rx="106" ry="0"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Indeed, the soluce was to place it in an HTML document. I've already tried but it ended bad.. weird.  Anyway, thank for your help, appreciated it !

Answer (score -1):

Corresponding to your sourcecode, the error is not coming from the svg itself, but from the code wrapping it.

!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
...
]>